# Create A COM object inside another COM object

Tags: c++, com, windows-ce, atl

I have the following interface. The interface returns  `ISystemCmds` interface as part of  `GetSystemCommandInterface` method. We are using ATL for creating the COM.

```
interface IDevice : IDispatch{  
 [id(1), helpstring("method Connect")] HRESULT Connect([in] VARIANT varPortNo);    
 [id(2), helpstring("method GetSystemCommandInterface")] HRESULT GetSystemCommandInterface([out,retval] ISystemCmds** pISystemCmd);    
};
```

What code should add (and where) for creating the COM object for `ISystemCmds`  if

a. I am creating the COM object for ISystemCmds as part of COM object creation of `IDevice`?
b. I am creating the COM object in `GetSystemCommandInterface`() method?

Comment: We need to go deeper! (sorry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ATL wizard to create the implementation of ISystemCmds. Then create the object through normal CoCreateInstance, or use the CComObject<> template (see method CreateInstance) if you need to initialize the object in a way that ISystemCmds does not support. Be aware that CComObject<>::CreateInstance() does not AddRef() your object like QueryInterface() and CoCreateInstance() do. AddRef the object before passing it along!

Answer (score 1):

Getting new COM objects is rather a heavy operation so I think you should consider a variant where one class implements several interfaces as I think it is a perfectly valid assumption that `ISystemCmds` is not going to outlive `IDevice`. So think about implementing both interfaces using the same class and calling `QueryInterface` inside of `GetSystemCommandInterface`.

Comment: You cannot implement two IDispatch interfaces, and expect that it will work with late binding clients. You *have* to do it this way.

Comment: I think the OP should precise if he needs IDispatch and the late binding functionality, still he may use some workaround for `ATL::IDispatchImpl` like described at <http://www.codeproject.com/KB/atl/IDispatchImplEx.aspx>

Comment: Sweet template! I suppose it cannot resolve name clashes between interface members (IX::X vs IY::X), but that can be designed away on the interface level.